# Adjusting UI for different platforms

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working on a Xamarin.Forms (Portable) using Visual Studio 2015.
The application allows me to retrieve information from a Database and display it.

I am able to display all the created records in a ListView on UWP. However, on Android they are not all showing up.

From my Menu Page, you can clearly see the big difference in terms of UI size. I am curious to know why this is happening on the Android platform.

Below are some of the relevant code. If you need to see more, please let me know.

**MenuPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="XamarinFormsDemo.Views.MenuPage"
    BackgroundImage="bg3.jpg">

    <StackLayout>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"
            Padding="30"
            HeightRequest="30"
            BackgroundColor="#24e97d">
            <Image Source="ebmspersonnellogo1.png"
                HeightRequest="40"/>
        </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            Padding="45,60,45,60">

            <Image x:Name="sales"
                Source="salesicon.png">

                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer
                    Tapped="SalesTapGestureRecognizer_OnTapped"
                    NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
            </Image>

            <Image x:Name="personnel"
                Source="personnelicon.png">
                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer
                        Tapped="PersonnelTapGestureRecognizer_OnTapped"
                        NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
            </Image>

            <Image x:Name="crm"
                Source="crmicon.png">
                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer
                        Tapped="CRMTapGestureRecognizer_OnTapped"
                        NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
            </Image>

            <Image x:Name="asset"
                Source="asseticon.png">
                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer

                            Tapped="AssetTapGestureRecognizer_OnTapped"
                            NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
            </Image>

            <Image x:Name="receivables"
                Source="receivables.png">
                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer
                        Tapped="ReceivablesTapGestureRecognizer_OnTapped"
                        NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
            </Image>

            <Image x:Name="prapprovals"
                Source="prapprovals.png">
                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer
                        Tapped="ApprovalsTapGestureRecognizer_OnTapped"
                        NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
            </Image>
        </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"
            Padding="30,10,30,10"
            HeightRequest="20"
            BackgroundColor="#24e97d"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            Opacity="0.5">
            <Label Text="© Copyright 2015   smesoft.com.ph   All Rights Reserved " 
                HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                VerticalOptions="Center" 
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

**MenuPage.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace XamarinFormsDemo.Views
{
    public partial class MenuPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MenuPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
        }

        private async void NavigateButton_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new EmployeeRecordsPage());
        }

        private async void SalesTapGestureRecognizer_OnTapped(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await sales.ScaleTo(0.95, 80, Easing.CubicOut);
            await sales.ScaleTo(1, 80, Easing.CubicIn);

            await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new SalesAndExpensePage());
        }

        private async void PersonnelTapGestureRecognizer_OnTapped(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await personnel.ScaleTo(0.90, 75, Easing.CubicOut);
            await personnel.ScaleTo(1, 75, Easing.CubicIn);

            await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new PersonnelPage());
        }

        private async void CRMTapGestureRecognizer_OnTapped(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await crm.ScaleTo(0.90, 75, Easing.CubicOut);
            await crm.ScaleTo(1, 75, Easing.CubicIn);

            await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new CRMPage());
        }


        private async void AssetTapGestureRecognizer_OnTapped(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await asset.ScaleTo(0.90, 75, Easing.CubicOut);
            await asset.ScaleTo(1, 75, Easing.CubicIn);

            await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new AssetManagementPage());
        }

        private async void ReceivablesTapGestureRecognizer_OnTapped(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await receivables.ScaleTo(0.90, 75, Easing.CubicOut);
            await receivables.ScaleTo(1, 75, Easing.CubicIn);

            await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new ReceivablesAndPayablesPage());
        }


        private async void ApprovalsTapGestureRecognizer_OnTapped(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            await prapprovals.ScaleTo(0.90, 75, Easing.CubicOut);
            await prapprovals.ScaleTo(1, 75, Easing.CubicIn);

            await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new ApprovalsPage());
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a screen shot of UWP and Android. First image is UWP, second image is Android.

[image: UWP screenshot]
[image: Android screenshot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all. Your view is awfully nested, which can lead to performance problems.

Second of all. You are saying you are using a ListView. However, I don't see it anywhere in your XAML. There you are just using a StackLayout and stacking views below each other.

This means that any item that cannot fit within the screen will not be displayed at all. Consider rewriting your UI and use a ListView instead. Your items are very similar to each other and only title, image and click handler differ from each other. Using a ListView could also eliminate repeating yourself as you do currently with all those tap handlers, and you could limit yourself to only have one.

You could have something like this:

```
public class MenuItemViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your ViewModel for the page:

```
public List<MenuItemViewModel> MenuItems { get; } = new List<MenuItemViewModel>();

MenuItems.Add(new MenuItemViewModel {
    Name = "Sales and Expense",
    ImageUrl = "salesicon.png"
});
MenuItems.Add(new MenuItemViewModel {
    Name = "Personnel",
    ImageUrl = "personnelicon.png"
});
...
```

Then in your XAML something like this:

```
<ListView x:Name="MenuList">
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ViewCell>
         <StackLayout Padding="15,0">
             <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
             <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" />
         </StackLayout>
      </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Then set `ItemsSource` of the ListView to your `MenuItems` from your ViewModel.

You can get the selected item by subscribing to `ItemSelected` on the ListView:

```
MenuList.ItemSelected += ItemSelected;

private async void ItemSelected(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
{
    var menuItem = e.Item as MenuItemViewModel;
    if (menuItem == null) return;

    Page nextPage = null;
    switch(menuItem.Name)
    {
         case "Sales and Expense":
            nextPage = new SalesAndExpensePage();
            break;
         case "Personnel":
            nextPage = new PersonnelPage();
            break;
    }

    await Navigation.PushModalAsync(nextPage);
}
```

Comment: It's true that I'm using ListView but actually not on that part. My mistake, sorry for that Sir. You said that using a StackLayout and stacking views below each other will not display all items that cannot fit within the screen. But there are still two items that was displayed, so how is that happening?